# Make ember to resolve hasMany relationship when loading

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm currently facing a big problems for days. I'm using ember simple-auth plugin which provide me a session object accessible through the code or the templates. That session object store the account information such as username, id and rights.

My models are like this :

```
App.Right = DS.Model.extend({
    label: DS.attr('string', { defaultValue: undefined })
});

App.Right.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        label: 'Admin'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        label: 'Manager'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        label: 'User'
    }
];

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr('string'),
    rights: DS.hasMany('right', {async: true})
});

App.User.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        username: "Someone",
        rights: [1]
    }
];
```

Then I have (as specified on the simple-auth documentation) this setup :

```
App.initializer({
    name: 'authentication',
    initialize: function(container, application) {
        Ember.SimpleAuth.Session.reopen({
            account: function() {
                var userId = this.get('userId');
                if (!Ember.isEmpty(userId)) {
                    return container.lookup('store:main').find('user', userId);
                }
            }.property('userId')
        });
    ...
    }
});
```

Inside one of my view I'm doing this:

```
this.get('context.session.account.rights').toArray()
```

but it gives me an empty array. That piece of code is executed inside an `Ember.computed` property.

The question is how can I resolve the childrens of account before rendering the view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I finally got it to work. It doesn't solve the original question because the original question was completely stupid. It's just IMPOSSIBLE to resolve relationships synchronously when you use the `async: true`. Trying to resolve it in advance is NOT the solution because you will still not know when it has actually resolved.

So here is the solution:

```
$.each(this.get('cellContent.buttonList'), function(i, button) {
    button.set('hasAccess', false);
    this.get('context.session.account').then(function(res) {
        res.get('rights').then(function(result) {
            button.set('hasAccess', Utils.hasAccess(result.toArray(), button.rights));
        });
    });
});
```

Using the following `cellContent.buttonList` definition:

```
buttonList: [
    Ember.Object.create({
        route: 'order',
        label: 'Consult',
        rights: 'all'
    }), Ember.Object.create({
        route: 'order.edit',
        label: 'Edit',
        rights: [1, 2]
    })
]
```

**Explanation**
We have to use `Ember.Object` in order to have access to the `set` method. Using an Ember object is very handy. It allows us to change the value of properties after the render process making the view to update according to the new value you just set.
Because it updates the view, you don't have to care anymore whether your model has resolved or not.

I hope this will help people as much as it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

Since async: true this.get('context.session.account.rights') will return a promise object so you will have to use this.get('context.session.account.rights').then(... see: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.RSVP.Promise.html#method_then

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't that simple. Doing what you suggest gives me a beautiful: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined```
Looks like, account itself has not yet resolve

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this issue: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/issues/138?

Comment: No it's not. The issue in the link was only how to access the session object. Now the problem is that the data are loaded asynchronously causing the rendering of the component to crash.

Comment: @BavoVanGeit: you were right but it needed a bit more reflexion.

The error ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined``` was thrown because ```context.session.account``` also return a promise which wasn't resolved. So I had to use a nested then.